# ERROR when creating a connectioFactory JMS websphere MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' not found.
please some one can help me to get mqjbnd64 
 this is my code

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory=null;
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/C:/CWMQv75-POT/JMS/JNDI Namespace");


    try{    
       Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
      // MQQueueManager qm = (MQQueueManager)ctx.lookup("QM");
       MQConnectionFactory cf = (MQConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("CF1");
     //  cf.createConnection().start();
       MQQueue q = (MQQueue) ctx.lookup("JMS1");
      connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("CF1");

        System.out.println("succes "+q.getBaseQueueManagerName().toString() + " " + q.getBaseQueueName()+" " +" " + cf.getChannel() );
    } catch (NamingException e)
    {
       System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
}
```

Comment: Have you installed MQ client or simply copied MQ Java/JMS jar files? mqjbnd64.dll will be in java\lib64 directory of MQ installation.

Answer (score 2):

> The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' not found

Questions:

1) Are you running your JMS application on the SAME serer as the queue manager or a different server?

2) When you defined your QCF, did you include host, port #, channel name?

3) Do you understand the difference between connecting to a queue manager in ***bindings mode*** vs ***client mode***?

You can ONLY connect in bindings mode if your application is running on the same server as the queue manager.  When connecting in bindings mode the JMS/Java MQ library uses the native MQ library, hence, it needs the mqjbnd64 shared library or DLL on Windows to perform the MQ API calls.

Most MQ applications do NOT reside on the same server as the queue manager and they will use client mode to connect to the remote queue manager and your QCF would look something like:

```
DEFINE QCF(MYQCF) QMANAGER(MQWL1) CHANNEL(TESTCHL) HOSTNAME(10.10.10.10) PORT(1414) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

One other thing I noticed:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/C:/CWMQv75-POT/JMS/JNDI Namespace");
```

that should be:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file://C:/CWMQv75-POT/JMS/JNDI Namespace");
```

You should have 2 forward slashes "//" after "file:".

Comment: this is my email if you can contact me please
diouri.khalil@gmail.com

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work if the Q&A gets siphoned off to email or other forums.  People have to be able to see the evolution of the questions and answers *here* for them to get any benefit from the site.  Voting to close unless the diagnostic discussion is captured by updating the question and in the comments. As Roger has noted, this is almost always an install/config issue, something other people would *really* need to see.